# How to convert multiline text representing as a indent tree to xml in perl?

Tags: xml, perl, tree

for example, the input is

```
    root
    ^^aa
    ^^^^bb
    ^^cc
    ^^dd
```

two ^^ represent an indent,  therefore aa is child of root, bb is child of aa.
aa,cc and dd are brothers, they are all children of root.

The output is a xml file, its content will be

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<dir name="root">
  <dir name="aa">
    <dir name="bb" />
  </dir>
  <dir name="cc" />
  <dir name="dd" />
</dir>
```

But i can't find the right perl script to solve this problem. 
So search for help, Thanks a lot.

Comment: 10 rep points to whoever can do that using CPAN

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aLibXML) for this task. You only need to know about the previous level and the previous element this way:

```
use XML::LibXML;

my $doc = XML::LibXML::Document->new();
my $previousLevel = 0;
my $previousElement;

foreach my $line (@data) {
    if($line =~ m/^(\^*)(.+)$/) {
        my $level = (length $1) / 2;
        my $name = $2;

        my $dir = $doc->createElement('dir');
        $dir->setAttribute('name', $name);

        if($level == 0) {
            $doc->setDocumentElement($dir);
        }
        elsif($level > $previousLevel) {
            $previousElement->addChild($dir);
        }
        elsif($level < $previousLevel) {
            $previousElement = $previousElement->parentNode()
               for ($level .. $previousLevel -1);
            $previousElement->addSibling($dir);
        }
        elsif($level == $previousLevel) {
            $previousElement->addSibling($dir);
        }

        $previousElement = $dir;
        $previousLevel = $level;
    }
}

print $doc->toString(2);
```

Answer (score -1):

You have all the info you need by comparing the depth of the current node and the depth of the preceding node.

```
my $last_depth = -1;
while (@input) {
   my $name = shift(@input);

   my $depth = 0;
   ++$depth while $name =~ s/^\^\^//;

   while ($depth <= $last_depth) {
      end_dir($last_depth);
      --$last_depth;
   }

   die if $depth != $last_depth + 1;

   start_dir($depth, $name);
   ++$last_depth;
}

while ($last_depth > -1) {
   end_dir($last_depth);
   --$last_depth;
}
```

Rest of the program

```
my %escapes = (
   '&' => '&amp;',
   '<' => '&lt;',
   '>' => '&gt;',
   '"' => '&quot;',
   "'" => '&apos;',
);

sub text_to_xml {
   my ($s) = @_;
   $s =~ s/([&<>'"])/$escapes{$1}/g;
   return $s;
}

sub start_dir { print(('  ' x $_[0]) . qq{<dir name="}.text_to_xml($_[1]).qq{">\n}); }
sub end_dir   { print(('  ' x $_[0]) . qq{</dir>\n}); }

my @input = split /\n/, <<'__EOI__';
root
^^aa
^^^^bb
^^cc
^^dd
__EOI__

binmode(STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-8)');
print(qq{<?xml version="1.0"?>\n});
```